# how to create dynamic id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a form where i generating dynamic field .

1. on that dynamic field i have a select option .  In that option two option is there for giving dimensions one in fit/in and other in m/cm
2. If i select fit then dimension will be in ft .  Otherwise in m/cm the code is working fine
3. But the problem is that when i creating dynamic field like 5 time then on that time 5 option is there if i select one only changes is happening .
4. In in one field option i know the reason because the id same for all dynamic id then i can create dynamic id for that select option.
5. just below here is dynamic generating field means if select five time its create 5 dynamic field i know its very broad to describe my problem but i need to solve

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $("#sel").on('change', function() {

    var counter = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    $('#parent').change('<div id="first' + count + '">text</div>');
    var html = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-9 control-label"><h3><strong>Item Details</strong></h3></label></div>';
    var html1 = '<div class="row"><div class="form-group"> <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-6 control-label">* Dimensions (Best Estimate):</label> <div class="col-sm-3"><select id="mySelect" class="form-control"><option>ft/in/lbs</option><option>m/cm/kg</option></select></div>\
  </div></div><br>';
    var html2 = '<div style="padding-left: 4cm;"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Length<?php echo str_repeat(' & nbsp ', 6);?></span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="length_m" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" size="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="length_md" id="myInput1" value="ft" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="length_cm" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" size="8" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="length_cmd" id="myInput2" value="in" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div>\
      </div>';
    var html3 = '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Width<?php echo str_repeat(' & nbsp ', 8);?></span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="width_m" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" size="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="width_md" id="myInput3" value="ft" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="width_cm" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" size="8" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="width_cmd" id="myInput4" value="in" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div>\
      </div>';
    var html4 = '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Height<?php echo str_repeat(' & nbsp ', 7);?></span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="height_m" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" size="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="height_md" id="myInput5" value="ft" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="height_cm" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" size="8" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="height_cmd" id="myInput6" value="in" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div>\
      </div>';
    var html5 = '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Weight<?php echo str_repeat(' & nbsp ', 6);?></span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="weight" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" size="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="weightd" id="myInput7" value="lbs" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Quantity&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="quantity" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="2" size="2" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div>\
      </div></div></br></br>';
    var html6 = '<div class="form-group"><label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Item description</label><div style="padding-left: 4cm;"><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="additional_detail" placeholder="Item description"></textarea></div>\
      </div></br></br></br>';
    count++;
    var str1 = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
      str1 += [html, html1, html2, html3, html4, html5, html6];
      str1 = str1.replace(/,/gi, "\n").replace(/^,/, "");
    }
    $("#inrlog").empty().append(str1);

  })
});
```

here is the code that take select option id on that id its change that field two different value one in ft/in other in m/cm

```js
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).find(':selected').data('value');
  var value1 = $(this).find(':selected').data('value1');
  var value2 = $(this).find(':selected').data('value2');
  $('#myInput1').attr('value', value);
  $('#myInput2').attr('value', value1);
  $('#myInput3').attr('value', value);
  $('#myInput4').attr('value', value1);
  $('#myInput5').attr('value', value);
  $('#myInput6').attr('value', value1);
  $('#myInput7').attr('value', value2);
});
```

Comment: Please, grammar, paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

according to your code, you need a dynamic select tag for the string html1. In The current code you have no loop for the html variable.

What you can do is, take a function called html1 instead of variable, and call that function in that loop and pass the counter(i) variable into that function and return the select tag as a string which will be dynamic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $("#sel").on('change', function() {

    var counter = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    $('#parent').change('<div id="first' + count + '">text</div>');
    var html = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-9 control-label"><h3><strong>Item Details</strong></h3></label></div>';
    
    var html2 = '<div style="padding-left: 4cm;"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Length<?php echo str_repeat(' & nbsp ', 6);?></span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="length_m" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" size="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="length_md" id="myInput1" value="ft" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="length_cm" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" size="8" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="length_cmd" id="myInput2" value="in" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div>\
      </div>';
    var html3 = '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Width<?php echo str_repeat(' & nbsp ', 8);?></span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="width_m" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" size="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="width_md" id="myInput3" value="ft" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="width_cm" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" size="8" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="width_cmd" id="myInput4" value="in" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div>\
      </div>';
    var html4 = '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Height<?php echo str_repeat(' & nbsp ', 7);?></span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="height_m" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" size="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="height_md" id="myInput5" value="ft" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="height_cm" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" size="8" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="height_cmd" id="myInput6" value="in" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div>\
      </div>';
    var html5 = '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Weight<?php echo str_repeat(' & nbsp ', 6);?></span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="weight" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="8" size="8" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="weightd" id="myInput7" value="lbs" maxlength="1" size="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly></div><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">Quantity&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><div class="input-group-addon"><input type="text" name="quantity" id="myInput" placeholder="" maxlength="2" size="2" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required></div>\
      </div></div></br></br>';
    var html6 = '<div class="form-group"><label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Item description</label><div style="padding-left: 4cm;"><textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="additional_detail" placeholder="Item description"></textarea></div>\
      </div></br></br></br>';
    count++;

###The function is here########

    function html1(i){
   return '<div class="row"><div class="form-group"> <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-6 control-label">* Dimensions (Best Estimate):</label> <div class="col-sm-3"><select id= i+"mySelect" class="form-control"><option>ft/in/lbs</option><option>m/cm/kg</option></select></div>\
  </div></div><br>'
  }


    var str1 = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
      str1 += [html, html1(i), html2, html3, html4, html5, html6];
      str1 = str1.replace(/,/gi, "\n").replace(/^,/, "");
    }
    $("#inrlog").empty().append(str1);

  })
});
```

In that function, the select tag is changed as follows, which take dynamic i values.

```
<select id= i+"mySelect" class="form-control"><option>ft/in/lbs</option><option>m/cm/kg</option></select>
```

Comment: Hello, did you try this?